# wget not returning same result as clicking on link in chrome browser

Tags: wget

I am trying to use wget to download an audio file from a link (which has no file extension). The issue is that clicking this link automatically starts a `.wav` file download but wget on the same link returns a file without a file extension. Passing the `-O file.wav` extension does not work as the file itself is not compatible.

I have tried

```
wget -O test.wav "[DOWNLOAD LINK]"
```

The above downloads a file in my directory which is **not audio.**

My problem can be replicated by going to https://captcha.com/demos/features/captcha-demo.aspx and clicking on the `href` associated with the element of class `class=BDC_SoundLink`.

[image]

### Questions:

1. Is there a way to get `wget` to return same result as clicking the link?
2. Is there a way to resolve the non audio file to audio file after `wget` does whatever it does?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It seems you cannot download this link if the captcha session is not initialized in your browser. You can test this by selecting "Copy link" in Chrome and opening it in Edge. Instead of an audio file, you get an error message. You have to find out how to initialize the captcha session with wget.

Comment: @VLL thanks for that I didnt even think to do that but that is a very helpful check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that when you use WGET, you're actually downloading a text file because the MIME type is Text.
When you browse the website through your webbrowser it actually gets the right captcha code from the server and then you're able to download the file with the right captcha code. You can see below in the dev tools that the captcha code is here.

[image: dev tools]

This sound file is linked to the captcha itself and each time you reload the captcha picture, the backend C# code of the asp.net page is giving a new captcha code.

That's why you can't download the captcha that way.

Comment: This is very helpful. Is it possible then to use use something like `selenium` to download? When I try click `a` tag using selenium is correctly plays the audio but does not download it.

Comment: Another way to frame my question then is "why is opening the devtools and clicking the href different from the button and can I get python to do that?"

Comment: It's just because on the backend you have a whole code running. I guess they are using the package NuGet [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Captcha/) here  to do so. You are trying to automate the download of a file which is protected by a captcha system, and the captcha does the job pretty well :)